# GreenDao Many to Many Relation

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, greendao

I use Greendao for my database mapping in Android. So far everything works great.

But now I have the following problem:

I have a Cluster and leaf Objects. A cluster contains many leaf objects.
If a cluster is zoomed it can split up in more clusters and more leafs. This is not a strict tree relationship it is more that a big cluster has a lots of leafs but a small cluster can have a subset of this leafs.

Basically a cluster has many leafs but leafs also are in multiple clusters, since the id of a leaf is unique and the relation to the cluster is saved in the leaf a leaf can only be in one cluster right?

The greendao homepage states that many to many relations are possible but how i can't get my head around it how to model this relation.

Is it possible to model such a relation or is the data structure a problem for GreenDao?

Comment: Not known with GreenDao so no help there, but I don't totally understand why this is a many-to-many relation? Imagining a tree with branches, and branches with leaves, branches belong to exactly 1 tree and leaves belong to exactly 1 branch. Why is yours different?

Comment: Because the leaf is no traditional leaf. A unique leaf can be attached to multiple branches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start with a quote from the [docs](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/relations/):

> While greenDAO does not support n:m relations directly as of now, you
>   can model the join table as a separate entity. In practice, you often
>   have “relation entities” with additional properties, so you might want
>   to do so anyway. In future releases, greenDAO might introduce direct
>   support of n:m relations.

So, in your case you have to model an entity, that is between Cluster and Leaf. Let's call this entity ClusterLeaf. To query leafs for a cluster efficiently, I'd suggest raw [queries](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/) because the QueryBuilder does not support joins yet.

Comment: How would such a ClusterLeaf look Codewise?

Comment: Properties: id, clusterId, leafId.

Comment: So every cluster has a list of ClusterLeafs and every leaf hast a list of clusterleafs. Ok I see I now have to figure out how to query and update that relations. Thanks for the quick response. Any ideas when this joins or this kind of queries will be supported?

Comment: Sorry, there's no time line for this feature yet. Btw, there are some breaking changes ahead in 1.3.0: https://plus.google.com/b/103605567853075245881/103605567853075245881/posts/Zqg5ya6N9Nf

Comment: Breaking as in great or in breaking compatibility ;)